# python name error: NameError: name 'Jewels' is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7

what is the mistake in below code? where to define the list variable Jewels?

```
for jew in range(0,Total_Jewels):
    Jewels[jew]=int(raw_input("Please Enter approx price for Jewel#"+str(jew+1)))
```

error

> Please Enter approx price for Jewel#111
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------- NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         1 for jew in range(0,Total_Jewels):
>   ----> 2     Jewels[jew]=int(raw_input("Please Enter approx price for Jewel#"+str(jew+1)))
>
> NameError: name 'Jewels' is not defined

Comment: That depends on the rest of the code; code you haven't included. Without more context, the only answer we can give you is "in a broader scope than the inside of the loop". And if you expect the list to be pre-populated, you're just overwriting the old data. You'd probably want to `append` to a new list instead of assigning over existing elements.

Comment: Just as the error says, you haven't defined `Jewels`.  This is coming from some other part of your code that you haven't shared.

Comment: While yes "Jewels[]" never defined as list because my understanding was like any other variable types in python, list variables don't need to explicitly defined.Its resolved now.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't fill a list in this way. Because you start with an empty list, `Jewels = []`, your attempt to assign to `Jewels[0]` will result in an `IndexError`. You can instead use the `list.append` method

```
jewels = []
for i in range(total_jewels):
    jewels.append(raw_input('Please Enter approx price for Jewel #{}: '.format(i)))
```

or a list comprehension

```
jewels = [raw_input('Please Enter approx price for Jewel #{}: '.format(i)) for i in range(total_jewels)]
```

Comment: I don't see what that has to do with their error. Plus, you *can* fill a list their way if the list is large enough.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your code looks like, so not sure what your asking.

Maybe try:

```
prices = []
for j in range(Total_Jewels):
    prices.append(input("Please enter approx price for Jewel#"+str(j+1)))
```